# html outlook mso-border-bottom-alt not working

Tags: outlook, border, html-email, email-client

Need to underline a text link that has a <sup>®</sup>

The underline for the ® is not lined up with the rest of the words so a border-bottom is used instead. But in Outlook 2016 and 2019, the border-bottom disappears.

I searched and found this mso-border-bottom-alt that are supposed to work.

Here is the code:

```
.border { 
mso-border-right-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
mso-border-bottom-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
mso-border-left-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
mso-border-top-alt: solid #903010 2pt; /* px works too */
}
```

It only works to add all borders but not just the bottom border.

[image: registration with borders]

Can someone tell me why this is not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you *why* it's not working, but only confirm that it isn't. That's just the way of email clients these days - things work, until they don't. Or don't work, until they do. It's software that is constantly being tinkered with without common standards.

However, I was able to make a workaround.

```html
This is <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none;border-bottom:1px solid blue"><!--[if mso]><span style="text-decoration:underline;line-height: 20px;"><![endif]-->registrated<!--[if mso]></span><![endif]--><sup><!--[if mso]><span style="text-decoration:underline;line-height: 20px;"><![endif]-->&reg;<!--[if mso]></span><![endif]--></sup></a>
```

The approach is as follows: since a normal underline in superscript is above the rest of the word, we can use `border-bottom` for all non-Outlook email clients. Then, we can use Outlook conditional code for Outlook, and thankfully a normal underline does work, when we set the line-height on the `<sup>` to the same line-height of the `<a>`.